# How can we evaluate DBSCAN parameters?

Tags: r, clustering

yes, DBSCAN parameters, and in particular the parameter **eps** (size of the epsilon neighborhood).
In the documentation we have a "*Look for the knee in the plot*".

Fine, but it requires a visual analysis. And it doesn't really work if we want to make things automatic.
So, I was wondering if it was possible to find a good eps in a few lines of code.

Let's imagine something like :

1. evaluate kNN distance
2. sort these values
3. scale them (so that
   the values are always between 0 and 1)
4. evaluate the derivative
5. find the first point where derivative is higher than a certain
   value, let's try with 1

In R, it would look like (using iris dataset as in the DBSCAN documentation) :

```
# evaluate kNN distance
dist <- dbscan::kNNdist(iris, 4)

# order result
dist <- dist[order(dist)]

# scale
dist <- dist / max(dist)

# derivative
ddist <- diff(dist) / ( 1 / length(dist))

# get first point where derivative is higher than 1
knee <- dist[length(ddist)- length(ddist[ddist > 1])]
```

and the result is **0.536** which looks quite good.
[image]

Is this approach relevant or totally nonsense ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OPTICS](http://www.dbs.informatik.uni-muenchen.de/Publikationen/Papers/OPTICS.pdf) gets rid of $\varepsilon$, you might want to have a look at it. Especially the **reachability plot** is a way to visualize what good choices of $\varepsilon$ in DBSCAN might be.

Wikipedia ([article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm)) illustrates it pretty well. The image on the top left shows the data points, the image on the bottom left is the reachability plot:

[image]

The $y$-axis are different values for $\varepsilon$, the valleys are the clusters. Each "bar" is for a single point, where the height of the bar is the minimal distance to the already printed points.

Comment: I'm a bit confused (but that's normal since I'm just starting to work with this kind of tools...) because according to the [doc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbscan/dbscan.pdf) a eps parameter still need to be set for OPTICS algorithm. So we don't really get rid of it, do we ?

Comment: The eps parameter of OPTICS is different. It is an upper bound, not a fixed value. It mainly has influence on how fast the algorithm runs.

Comment: Indeed but, at the end, if we want to extract clusters we have to make a visual analysis of the reachability plot and set xi parameter manually Is there a way to set it in a cleaner way ? (I'm going off topic...)

Answer (score 2):

If you go for an automatic solution, you may as well just decide that 80% of your points should be core points, and **choose the 80% quantile of the 4-NN distances**.

Looking at the derivative etc. to formally define a "knee" is fragile, this will not work in my opinion. Because you cannot compare distances to ranks.

But:

- Several heuristics for DBSCAN parameterization have been proposed over the last 20 years.
- Several enhancements of DBSCAN such as OPTICS and HDBSCAN* have been published, that get rid of the epsilon parameter (in favor of a graphical approach, e.g. OPTICS plots).

In the end, **having parameters is a feature, not a limitation**. Cluster analysis is not something to fully automate. It is an explorative method. You try it, change parameters, try it again, change parameters again, ... until you have *learned* something about your data. Any method that does not allow you to reiterate is badly designed.