# DBSCAN: How does a quantile of kNN relate to the share core points?

Tags: clustering, dbscan

I read [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/11823) by Anony-Mousse to an other question related to density based clustering and how to potentially come up with an eps. It states, that if you want **90% of you points to be core points**, you can use the **80% quantile of the 4-NN distances** as your eps.

I just don't understand how the 90% core points exactly relate to the 80%-quantile of the 4-NN distances. Of course I get that they are related somehow, but I dont get the exact chain.

I've been thinking (and reading) about this for a while now and just can't come up with the answer, although it's probably pretty obvious?

Comment: Have you considered that this might be a trivial typo, and that both values should be the same?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse ... No. Thanks and sorry. ;)